# NSGI10 not correclty displayed in ckan ngsi view

Tags: ckan, fiware-cygnus

My  SW context :

1. orion broker ( 0.27.0-next) + cygnus 0.13.0 --> started with docker
2. personal CKAN instance (2.4.1)

I have NGSI notifs (with geolocs)  that came from the orion broker, are processed by cygnus and  routed to CKAN backend. Perfect!
so i have some  dataset/ressource created in  my CKAN and i can see them 
listed in the portal with NGSI10 tag 
but when i try to see the map ,the  geographic view with map  is not displayed. i expect some vizualization like :
https://data.lab.fiware.org/dataset/equipamientos-de-sevilla/resource/43031ec7-0b0e-4960-9e53-78035ccf9f8c

but i dont have this display only a 'recline grid view'

i can recompile/deploy the cygnus and modify the  CKAN backend  but its not clear if its the place to modify  something

the burden seems to be much more on CKAN side and CKAN plugins ? right ?
Any Idea ?

Thanks

Phil

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think the ideal thing would be Cygnus could infer the "data type" and crate the most appropriate view in CKAN. But that's a bit complex for the time being, basically because the types sent by Orion have no semantic, and are simply "informative" about the data. I mean, the type could be "string", "integer", "geopoint" or "potato".

Being said that, I think you can add more views to the resource by using the CKAN API (this API is the one Cygnus uses to create the "recline view", btw):

http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/#ckan.logic.action.create.resource_view_create

This should work (tailor it with the appropiate view, token, etc):

```
$ curl -X POST http://ckan_host:80/api/3/action/resource_view_create -d '{"resource_id":"my-resource-id", "view_type":"recline_grid_view", "title":"My recline grid"}' -H "Authorization:my-api-key"
```

Comment: Hi thanks  for the answer.  I have progressed up to have the display of the form   with NGSI resource header  and it tries to Load the json in the map.     but at the end  i got a 409 conflict  and under the  resource name i have URL: http://.... and not **CB** http://....